# NSFetchRequest using NSPredicate

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a NSArray of all results of a filtered search through a core data database in this way:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"AllFiles" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@", userID];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderNumber == %d", folderNumber];
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileType == %@", type];

NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2, p3]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:fetchPredicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray* returnArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The files are created in this way:

```
AllFiles *newFile = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllFiles"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
newFile.userID = userID;
newFile.folderNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", folderNumber];
....
```

As you can see I am trying to filter the results given some of the parameters:

```
@"userID == %@", userID
```

However all results are returned, without filtering... Any ideas why?

Comment: You are using an OR predicate, at least one of those 3 is matching for all. My money is on file type

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks for pointing that out, it should be an AND. How do I make it an AND?

Comment: Wait, andPredicateWithSubpredicates might do the job

Comment: FYI, you don't have to create fetch request programmatically. You can define it directly in your CoreData model.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an OR predicate, at least one of those 3 is matching for all. I suspect `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileType == %@", type]` is gathering all your files

Try compositing an AND like so...

```
NSPredicate *idPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@", userID];
NSPredicate *folderNumPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderNumber == %d", folderNumber];
NSPredicate *typePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileType == %@", type];

NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[idPredicate, folderNumPredicate, typePredicate];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:fetchPredicate];
```

Bear in mind that `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` and `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` return a `NSPredicate` so they can be composited together in complex ways if you need.